# How to specify the default network interface on an Android virtual machine?

Tags: adb, networking, virtualization, ethernet

I get this error when trying to ping any device in my network: network is unreachable.

But it works normally when I specify the interface: `ping -I eth0 google.com`

How to make `eth0` my default interface on the Android 13 virtual machine on a laptop?

Comment: I think this question is related to network topic, rather than android. You should read about ICMP when using ping(sometimes administrator can turn off icmp response), routing tables (route -n).

Comment: Is your phone rooted?

Comment: I'm using running android platform as virtual machine on my laptop